# How can I install stubby on a Raspberry PI?

Tags: apt, software-installation, raspbian

Is there an apt repository that will allow me to install stubby on a raspberry Pi?

```
apt-get install stubby
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package stubby
```

I'm on Raspbian 9 stretch

```
cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"                                                                                                                                         
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: I asked for a repository, I'm aware I could build from source.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Raspbian repository that includes Stubby.

In order to install it from a repository, you'll have to install Debian or Ubuntu on your Raspberry Pi as Stubby is available from those repositories. You could add one of Debian or Ubuntu's repositories and install it from there but you'd have to do the same with its dependencies which could ruin your system because the versions of those packages may not be compatible with what's needed in Raspbian. You could also end up inadvertently installing other packages from the Debian or Ubuntu repositories which could end up causing the same issues.

Perhaps you prefer to use a repository but the best way to get it is to build it from the source code which is available here: https://github.com/getdnsapi/stubby